# Iterating with Django ORM through large datasets is slow

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django ORM to get data out of a database with a few million items. However, computation takes a while (40 minutes+), and I'm not sure how to pin point where the issue is located.

Models I've used:

```
class user_chartConfigurationData(models.Model):
    username_chartNum = models.ForeignKey(user_chartConfiguration, related_name='user_chartConfigurationData_username_chartNum')
    openedConfig = models.ForeignKey(user_chartConfigurationChartID, related_name='user_chartConfigurationData_user_chartConfigurationChartID')
    username_selects = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blockName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    variable = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.username_chartNum)
    order = models.IntegerField()

class data_parsed(models.Model):
    setid = models.ForeignKey(sett, related_name='data_parsed_setid', primary_key=True)
    setid_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index = True)
    block = models.CharField(max_length=2000, db_index = True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=2000, db_index = True)
    time = models.IntegerField(db_index = True)
    time_string = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.setid)

class unique_variables(models.Model):
    setid = models.ForeignKey(sett, related_name='unique_variables_setid')
    setid_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index = True)
    block = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index = True)
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index = True)
    variable = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index = True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=2000, db_index = True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("setid", "block", "variable", "stage", "value"),)
```

The code I'm running is looping through data_parsed, with relevant data that matches between user_chartConfigurationData and unique_variables.

```
#After we get the tab, we will get the configuration data from the config button. We will need the tab ID, which is chartNum, and the actual chart
#That is opened, which is the chartID.
chartIDKey = user_chartConfigurationChartID.objects.get(chartID = chartID)
for i in user_chartConfigurationData.objects.filter(username_chartNum = chartNum, openedConfig = chartIDKey).order_by('order').iterator():
    iterator = data_parsed.objects.all().iterator()

    #We will loop through parsed objects, and at the same time using the setid (unique for all blocks), which contains multiple
    #variables. Using the condition, we can set the variable gte (greater than equal), or lte (less than equal), so that the condition match
    #the setid for the data_parsed object, and variable condition
    for contents in iterator:
        #These are two flags, found is when we already have an entry inside a dictionary that already
        #matches the same setid. Meaning they are the same blocks. For example FlowBranch and FlowPure can belong
        #to the same block. Hence when we find an entry that matches the same id, we will put it in the same dictionary.
        #Added is used when the current item does not map to a previous setid entry in the dictionary. Then we will need
        #to add this new entry to the array of dictionary (set_of_pk_values). Otherwise, we will be adding a lot
        #of entries that doesn't have any values for variables (because the value was added to another entry inside a dictionary)
        found = False
        added = False
        storeItem = {}

        #Initial information for the row
        storeItem['block'] = contents.block
        storeItem['username'] = contents.username
        storeItem['setid'] = contents.setid
        storeItem['setid_hash'] = contents.setid_hash

        if (i.variable != ""):
            for findPrevious in set_of_pk_values:
                if(str(contents.setid) == str(findPrevious['setid'])):
                    try:
                        items = unique_variables.objects.get(setid = contents.setid, variable = i.variable)
                        findPrevious[variableName] = items.value
                        found = True
                        break
                    except:
                        pass
            if(found == False):
                try:
                    items = unique_variables.objects.get(setid = contents.setid, variable = i.variable)
                    storeItem[variableName] = items.value
                    added = True
                except:
                    pass
        if(found == False and added == True):
            storeItem['time_string'] = contents.time_string
            set_of_pk_values.append(storeItem)
```

I've tried to use select_related() or prefetch_related(), since it needs to go to unique_variables object and get some data, however, it still takes a long time.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, have a look at [django_debug_toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.2/). It will tell you how many queries you execute, and how long they last. Can't really live without this package when I have to optimize something =).

PS: Execution will be even slower.

**edit:** You may also want to enable [db_index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#db-index) for the fields you use to filter with or [index_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#index-together) for more than one field. Ofc, measure the times between your changes so you make sure which option is better.